# Triangulating Riemann surfaces by using non-constant meromorphic functions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

Let $X$ be a connected Riemann surface, i.e. $X$ is a one dimensional connected complex manifold (Hausdorff and second-countable as a topological space). The following is a classical result:

> **Theorem (Radò 1925)**
>
> A connected real surface is triangulable if and only if it admits a
> countable basis.

Moreover, there is a very nice way to produce a triangulation on any connected compact Riemann surface by using the existence of a non-constant meromorphic function on it. In fact if $f:X\to \overline{\mathbb{C}}$ is meromorphic with $X$ compact, then we can find a (finite) triangulation of the Riemann sphere given by $\Delta_1,\dots,\Delta_k$ such that the image under $f$ of every ramified point is a vertex of the chosen triangulation and such that $f$ restricted to the interior of each component in $f^{-1}(\Delta_j)$ is injective. Notice that we have a finite number of ramification points since $X$ is compact. At this point is quite clear that we can lift this triangulation of $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ to one of $X$.

So now a question arises naturally: is there a way to prove the existence of non-constant meromorphic function on $X$ without using integration and the existence of a triangulation?

The answer is positive (and it holds in general even if $X$ is not compact) and the proof is quite simple provided you are familiar with Green's functions and harmonic analysis.

Now my problem is this: pick $X$ to be a connected one dimensional complex "manifold" (non necessarily compact) by requiring that the underlying topological space is only Hausdorff. Then, we know that (or at least believe who proved this) there exists a non-constant meromorphic function $f:X\to\overline{\mathbb{C}}$. I would like to apply the same argument as above to produce a triangulation of $X$ (hence proving it is second-countable using the Radò's Theorem) by starting with one of $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$. The issue is that no we don't know if $f$ has a finite number of ramification points and I think this could be a problem in applying the previous argument. So, my final question is:

> **Question**
>
> Is there a way to produce a triangulation of a connected one
> dimensional complex "manifold" $X$ (not necessarily compact) whose
> underlying topological space is only Hausdorff by using the existence
> of a non-constant meromorphic function?

Comment: Actually there is a recent remarkable result that on any open Riemann surface there is a meromorphic function with 3 critical values arXiv:2103.16702, but I doubt that this gives a better proof of Rado's theorem:-) Rado's theorem is not very difficult, may I ask why are you looking for an alternative proof?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Our proof in that paper does use Rado's theorem, so it doesn't give a new (let alone "better") proof of Rado's theorem. :) As far as we are aware, even the fact that every (not necessarily compact) Riemann surface is a cover of the sphere branched over only finitely many values is new.

Comment: However, if you only want to know that the surface has countable topology (from which the existence of a triangulation follows), then of course having a non-constant meromorphic function is more than enough (see Lemma 23.2 in Forster's "Lectures on Riemann Surfaces").